# Безопасность и динамическая выдача статических сайтов

Tags: веб-программирование, безопасность

Есть три вопроса [пока что] по поводу генераторов статических сайтов (SSG). Понимаю что вопросы общие, но все же решил задать их здесь:

1. Если правильно понимаю, статическую html-страницу взломать невозможно, разве что взломать ФТП. Но возможно ли взломать сам генератор, если он хостится на сервере и например написан с помощью РНР? Или сам генератор не совсем такой как я себе представляю т.е. не такой как традиционные CMS?
2. Как происходит динамическая выдача например товаров интернет-магазина при фильтрации? Ведь предварительно сгенерирована толька страница категории со всеми товарами данной категории.
3. Можно ли решить проблему отсутствия базы данных простым файлом например в виде РНР-массива или JSON?

И вообще, буду благодарен за любые мысли по поводу такого способа разработки сайтов, любые известные вам преимущества и недостатки.

Comment: Ничего из перечисленного для среднестатистических статических сайтов вообще не используется. Генератор если и есть, то я не слышал о том, чтоб его помещали на сервер

Comment: А где же находится сам генератор? На локалке что ли?

Comment: За других точно не скажу, но лично на моих статических сайтах - на локалке, ага) Зачем он мне на сервере

Comment: Но сервер т.е. серверная часть насколько понимаю в любом случае нужна чтобы страницы генерировать. Или как вы их генерируете?

Comment: Генератор сгенерировал страницы и положил их в папочку — я загружаю папочку на сервер, откуда страницы раздаёт простой nginx без всяких php, всё.

Comment: Это понятно. Я имею в виду сам генератор у вас на локалке страницы генерирует без серверной части? Если да, то как?

Comment: Те генераторы, которые использовал я, были обычными программами, которые запускались в командной строке, создавали папочку со страницами согласно прописанным настройкам и завершались — серверная часть им нафиг не нужна. Вот так, например, выглядит генератор Pelican: https://i.stack.imgur.com/53rV8.png - генераторы Sphinx, Jekyll и Nanoc выглядят похоже. Генераторы «такие как традиционные CMS» лично мне не попадались